# Select all records with max DateTime using where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server 2008 Express.

I have a table called `Table1` which has `First_Name` and `Order_Date_Time` columns.

I want a SQL query which can select all records where `First_Name` = `Alex` and with max `Order_Date_Time`. The table contains multiple dates with exact same date.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with C#, if you are just looking for a SQL query

Comment: What output are you expecting? Do you just want the max Order_Date_Time for Alex? As in a single value?

Comment: Tom Dee. I want all the records which First_Name = "Alex" and with max dateTime. I will save the result in DataTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the correct result, and is pretty concise.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Order_Date_Time = (select MAX(Order_Date_Time) FROM Table1) and First_name = 'Alex'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this query returns only one record. say I have 1000 records in the database. I have 10 records which contains Alex and with max date and  these 10 records has exact date. i want to select those 10 records

Comment: Do you have multiple max dates that are the exact same date? Because your question says you want the max date with the name alex, so normally you would get only 1 record returned. You can also try:
Select * from Table1 where First_Name = 'Alex'

Comment: yes I have multiple dates with exact same date. can you please modify the answer. tnx

Answer (score 0):

One simple method that has good performance with the right indexes is:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.order_date_time = (select max(tt1.order_date_time) from table1 tt1 where tt1.first_name = t1.first_name);
```

The right index in `table1(name, order_date_time)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select top (1) with ties t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.First_Name = 'Alex'
order by row_number() over(partition by t1.first_name order by t1.order_date_time desc);
```

Comment: sorry what is t1?

Comment: @Sam. . . `t1` is table alise & `table1` is table_name which needs to replace with your table name.

Answer (score 0):

This will give all the records which contain Alex. That seems to be what you're looking from your comment.

```
SELECT First_Name, Order_Date_Time
FROM Table1
WHERE First_Name = 'Alex'
```

Comment: No. this will only return the two columns with all available records.